# How to stop Mathematica rounding the last digit of a number when converting it to string using ToString?

Tags: output, wolfram-mathematica, rounding, tostring

In Mathematica 8, numbers with no more than 16 significant digits are converted correctly, e.g.

```
ToString[
NumberForm[0.000001234567891234567, Infinity , 
ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
]
```

gives "0.000001234567891234567".

However numbers with more than 16 significant digits are rounded, e.g.

```
ToString[
 NumberForm[0.0000012345678912345678, Infinity , 
  ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
 ]
```

gives "0.000001234567891234568". How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would prefer the exponential form with 1.23456789e-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should explicitly specify the precision of your number using [`NumberMarks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberMarks.html):

```
ToString[NumberForm[0.0000012345678912345678`17, Infinity, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]]
```

> ```
> "0.0000012345678912345678"
> ```

The reason of the problem is that your number is interpreted as a `MachinePrecision` number. If you simply add one zero to the end of this number the problem disappears because such (new!) number is interpreted as an arbitrary precision number:

```
0.00000123456789123456780 // InputForm
```

> ```
> 1.2345678912345678`17.091514977603566*^-6
> ```

```
0.00000123456789123456780 // MachineNumberQ
```

> ```
> False
> ```

while your number is interpreted as a `MachinePrecision` number:

```
0.0000012345678912345678 // InputForm
```

> ```
> 1.2345678912345679*^-6
> ```

```
0.0000012345678912345678 // MachineNumberQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. I studied the topics of precision and accuracy in Mathematica documentation, but didn't understand how to solve my problem.  

I used explicit input of a number in my question in order to simplify it. The actual problem is to import numbers from .mat (matlab) file and write them to a text file with the same number of digits as in .mat file. So, I cannot manipulate input as you described, as it's not even text.

Comment: I don't have Matlab installed, therefore I use Mathematica for that seemingly simple task. I thought that once Mathematica is designed for working with numbers, and it can read .mat files, that simple task can be implemented easily. Now I've been devoting to it already half a day... Do you have any hints?

Comment: I suggest you to create specific question about importing .mat-files on the [*Mathematica*-dedicated site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).  An example file with which you have problems should be included/referenced in the question along with the code you currently use for importing it.

Comment: if you just want to write back out with exactly the same digits, import and export as strings.